How to detect face using camera package and google_mlkit_face_detection package in flutter?
I try to use method channel for face detect but it not work as expected,
I expecting using camera package and google_mlkit_face_detection package to detect face on live camera.
try {
      cameraController.initialize().then(
        (value) {
          setState(
            () {
              cameraController.startImageStream(
                (image) {
                  try {
                    debugPrint('camera_no formate${image.format.raw}');
                    debugPrint('camera_no size${image.planes.length}');

                final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();

                for (Plane plane in image.planes) {
                  allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
                }

                final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

                final imageSize =
                    Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

                final imageRotation = InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(
                        cameraDescription.sensorOrientation) ??
                    InputImageRotation.rotation0deg;

                final imageFormat =
                    InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw) ??
                        InputImageFormat.nv21;

                final metaData = InputImageMetadata(
                  size: imageSize,
                  rotation: imageRotation,
                  format: imageFormat,
                  bytesPerRow: image.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
                );

                final faceDetector = FaceDetector(options: option);

                final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
                  bytes: bytes,
                  metadata: metaData,
                );

                faceDetector.processImage(inputImage).then((value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    debugPrint('camera_no face detected${value.length}');
                  }
                  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                    debugPrint('camera_no face detected${value.length}');
                  }
                });
              } catch (e) {
                debugPrint('camera_no ERORR$e');
              }
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint('camera_initilize_error:- $e');
}`

I used this code to detect face on live but it did not work also no error throw when i show my face on camera it still say camera_no face detected 0

can you please format your code, beginning of the code is shown as text and then rest looks fine

now updated can u know resolve my issue ?
